# Type cast data types using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a file which has all datatypes as string. I want to type cast the data.

```
for s3_file in keys:
    analytics_df = pd.read_csv(s3_file, encoding="utf8")
    analytics_df = analytics_df.juice.astype(float).fillna(0.0)
    print(analytics_df.dtypes)
```

I am getting these errors:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'
```

Comment: Try replacing the “None” strings with np.nan. Then cast to float.

Comment: replace `analytics_df.juice.astype(float).fillna(0.0)` by `pd.to_numeric(analytics_df['juice'], errors='coerce').fillna(0.0)`